# Will upgrading to Windows 7 Professional from Home Premium remove Media Center?

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade, windows-media-center, license

My computer came with a copy of Windows 7 Home Premium. If I upgrade it to Windows 7 Professional, what will happen to Media Center? Will it be deleted because it's not available in Professional, or will it be kept because I also have a license for Home Premium? (or just because it was already on there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Media Center is included with Home, Pro, Ultimate](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/compare?T1=tab15) and [Enterprise](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-media-center) so it will not be removed during an upgrade to Pro.

[Windows 7 "Anytime" Upgrade is the easiest least expensive way to upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/shop/windows-anytime-upgrade), be sure to keep your anytime upgrade key somewhere safe.

Comment: Confirmed here. I will only buy Professional on any Windows OS and Win7 x64 comes with Windows Media Center as well.